# Uncaught TypeError: Unsupported operand types: string * int - Trying to Convert plugin to run on php8.2 (from 7.4)

Tags: php

In trying to convert a plugin to run on php8.2 from 7.4 I am getting the following error.

```
Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Unsupported operand types: string * int in /home/851390.cloudwaysapps.com/ctbcfdcbzf/public_html/wp-content/plugins/book-a-room/bookaroom-meetings-public.php:127 Stack trace: #0 /home/851390.cloudwaysapps.com/ctbcfdcbzf/public_html/wp-content/plugins/book-a-room/bookaroom-meetings-public.php(91): bookaroom_public::showForm_checkHoursError() #1 /home/851390.cloudwaysapps.com/ctbcfdcbzf/public_html/wp-includes/shortcodes.php(433): bookaroom_public::mainForm() #2 [internal function]: do_shortcode_tag() #3 /home/851390.cloudwaysapps.com/ctbcfdcbzf/public_html/wp-includes/shortcodes.php(273): preg_replace_callback() #4 /home/851390.cloudwaysapps.com/ctbcfdcbzf/public_html/wp-content/plugins/elementor/includes/widgets/shortcode.php(130): do_shortcode() #5 /home/851390.cloudwaysapps.com/ctbcfdcbzf/public_html/wp-content/plugins/elementor/includes/base/controls-stack.php(2297): Elementor\Widget_Shortcode->render() #6 /home/851390.cloudwaysapps.com/ctbcfdcbzf/public_html/wp-content/plugins/elementor/includes/base/widget-base.php(614): Elementor\Controls_Stack->render_by_mode() #7 /home/851390.cloudwaysapps.com/ctbcfdcbzf/public_html/wp-content/plugins/elementor/includes/base/widget-base.php(755): Elementor\Widget_Base->render_content() #8 /home/851390.cloudwaysapps.com/ctbcfdcbzf/public_html/wp-content/plugins/elementor/includes/base/element-base.php(464): Elementor\Widget_Base->print_content() #9 /home/851390.cloudwaysapps.com/ctbcfdcbzf/public_html/wp-content/plugins/elementor/includes/base/element-base.php(1375): Elementor\Element_Base->print_element() #10 /home/851390.cloudwaysapps.com/ctbcfdcbzf/public_html/wp-content/plugins/elementor/includes/base/element-base.php(464): Elementor\Element_Base->print_content() #11 /home/851390.cloudwaysapps.com/ctbcfdcbzf/public_html/wp-content/plugins/elementor/includes/base/element-base.php(1375): Elementor\Element_Base->print_element() #12 /home/851390.cloudwaysapps.com/ctbcfdcbzf/public_html/wp-content/plugins/elementor/includes/base/element-base.php(464): Elementor\Element_Base->print_content() #13 /home/851390.cloudwaysapps.com/ctbcfdcbzf/public_html/wp-content/plugins/elementor/core/base/document.php(1749): Elementor\Element_Base->print_element() #14 /home/851390.cloudwaysapps.com/ctbcfdcbzf/public_html/wp-content/plugins/elementor/core/base/document.php(1144): Elementor\Core\Base\Document->print_elements() #15 /home/851390.cloudwaysapps.com/ctbcfdcbzf/public_html/wp-content/plugins/elementor/includes/frontend.php(1179): Elementor\Core\Base\Document->print_elements_with_wrapper() #16 /home/851390.cloudwaysapps.com/ctbcfdcbzf/public_html/wp-content/plugins/elementor/includes/frontend.php(1074): Elementor\Frontend->get_builder_content() #17 /home/851390.cloudwaysapps.com/ctbcfdcbzf/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(324): Elementor\Frontend->apply_builder_in_content() #18 /home/851390.cloudwaysapps.com/ctbcfdcbzf/public_html/wp-includes/plugin.php(205): WP_Hook->apply_filters() #19 /home/851390.cloudwaysapps.com/ctbcfdcbzf/public_html/wp-includes/post-template.php(256): apply_filters() #20 /home/851390.cloudwaysapps.com/ctbcfdcbzf/public_html/wp-content/plugins/elementor/modules/page-templates/module.php(190): the_content() #21 [internal function]: Elementor\Modules\PageTemplates\Module->print_callback() #22 /home/851390.cloudwaysapps.com/ctbcfdcbzf/public_html/wp-content/plugins/elementor/modules/page-templates/module.php(207): call_user_func() #23 /home/851390.cloudwaysapps.com/ctbcfdcbzf/public_html/wp-content/plugins/elementor/modules/page-templates/templates/header-footer.php(19): Elementor\Modules\PageTemplates\Module->print_content() #24 /home/851390.cloudwaysapps.com/ctbcfdcbzf/public_html/wp-includes/template-loader.php(106): include('/home/851390.cl...') #25 /home/851390.cloudwaysapps.com/ctbcfdcbzf/public_html/wp-blog-header.php(19): require_once('/home/851390.cl...') #26 /home/851390.cloudwaysapps.com/ctbcfdcbzf/public_html/index.php(17): require('/home/851390.cl...') #27 {main} thrown in /home/851390.cloudwaysapps.com/ctbcfdcbzf/public_html/wp-content/plugins/book-a-room/bookaroom-meetings-public.php on line 127
```

The offending code on line 127 is:

```
$validStart     = strtotime( date( 'Y-m-d' ) ) + ( get_option( 'bookaroom_reserveBuffer' ) * 24 * 60 * 60 );
```

Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated!

I have tried converting the first bit to integer with int / float, with no success.

Comment: What is the value of `get_option( 'bookaroom_reserveBuffer' )`? You'll get this error if it's not a numeric string.

Comment: @Nick The error implies that it's not a numeric string, so converting it to an int will likely get an error as well.

Answer (score 0):

That option is apparently supposed to contain a number of days. You'll get this error if it's an empty string. Use a ternary to provide a default value in this case.

```
$buffer_days = get_option( 'bookaroom_reserveBuffer' ) ?: 1;
$validStart     = strtotime( date( 'Y-m-d' ) ) + ( $buffer_days * 24 * 60 * 60 );
```

If it contains some other non-numeric string, you'll still get the error. But you should probably fix that by correcting the option. You could use a `try/catch` to catch the error and produce a more useful error message for the end user, though.